# InternetExplorerMedium Class not registered error only on my PC

Tags: vba, windows

```
Public Sub test()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
End Sub
```

Above code works on my Window 10 64bit Enterprise workstation, but gives below error while running on my Window 10 64bit Pro:

> Run-time error '-2147418113(8000ffff)': Class not registered

Both are legit window copy and both has the same references / libraries (i.e Copied the exact excel file from one station to another).

Any ideas?

Comment: Cursory search shows remedies typically involve Windows security patch differences or hotfixes available from MS.  Most likely the problem is not related to your workbook at all.

Comment: @ionizing thank I will find out which hotfix i'm missing